# Query elements if their array of objects has properties with repeated elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

By having a collection with documents like these:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Name1",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            "Name" : "Name1",
            "Type" : "One"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "2",
            "Name" : "Name2",
            "Type" : "One"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5",
            "Name" : "Name5",
            "Type" : "Two"
        },
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "Name" : "Name2",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "3",
            "Name" : "Name3",
            "Type" : "One"
        }, 
                {
            "_id" : "4",
            "Name" : "Name4",
            "Type" : "Two"
        }, 
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "Name" : "Name3",
    "Children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "7",
            "Name" : "Name7",
            "Type" : "Two"
        }, 
                {
            "_id" : "6",
            "Name" : "Name6",
            "Type" : "Two"
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I want to query documents only if *Children* contains objects with repeated *Type* properties. For example object **1** has *Children* of three objects, property *Type* of which occurs twice (One, One, Two). Object **3** has two *Children* objects both of which has `Type = Two`. Object **2** has all unique *Children* (One, Two). So query will match objects **1** and **3**.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.. The Idea behind this, we will have the total children and compare it with after removing duplicates. If both count dont match, then we will get it as documents

- `$reduce` to count the total children and will have a duplicate Children (`dupChildren`)
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$project` to remove unwanted data. Since we need to match with the `$type`, we remove others in the `dupChildren`
- `$group` to reconstruct the array to remove the duplicate `type`,
- `$size` to count the `dupChildren` array
- `$match` to eliminate if both totalChildren and count are **equal**
- `$project` to remove unwanted fields

Here is the script

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalChildren: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Children",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [ "$$value", 1 ]
          }
        }
      },
      dupChildren: "$Children"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$dupChildren"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "dupChildren._id": 0,
      "dupChildren.Name": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      Name: { $first: "$Name" },
      Children: { $first: "$Children" },
      totalChildren: { $first: "$totalChildren" },
      dupChildren: { $addToSet: "$dupChildren" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      count: { $size: "$dupChildren" }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [ "$totalChildren", "$count" ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      dupChildren: 0,
      count: 0,
      totalChildren: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o1y641Rjghz)**

Comment: Thank you for your effort, actually it solves the problem, but not in my case, cause I have a very big document, I can't list all the properties in $group operator